# Doubly magic isotopes

Tags: soft-question, nuclear-physics, atomic-physics

I understand the definition of a magic number in nuclear physics to mean a number of either protons or neutrons to completely fill a nuclear shell. I see here the term "doubly magic" used for 78Ni:

http://inspirehep.net/record/1093563/plots?ln=en

What does doubly magic mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that both neutron shell and proton shell have been filled.

Neutrons and protons have different isospin values, hence they can have all other quantum numbers equal. This means, in the context of Shell Model, that they will occupy different shells and the filling of neutron shells is independent from the filling of proton shells.

Hence when a nucleus has completed each of the both types of shell, it contains a magic number of protons and a magic number of neutrons. Thus doubly magic.